# Four positive numerator-1 fractions summing to 3/7

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

This year's seventh-grade olympiad sponsored by Tel Aviv University, round two, held a couple of days ago, had this (translated by yours truly) as its third question:

> Find four distinct natural numbers, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, such that $$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c+\frac1d=\frac37$$

---

My solution:$$\begin{array}{rl}\frac37&=\frac17+.\overline{285714}\\&=\frac17+\frac15+.0\overline{857142}\\&=\frac17+\frac15+\frac6{70}\\&=\frac17+\frac15+\frac1{70}+\frac1{14}\end{array}$$

Tweaking that a bit led me to$$\frac17+\frac14+\frac1{32}+\frac1{224}$$

Question: Are there more solutions? Especially: Are there infinitely many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The greedy algorithm](//nrich.maths.org/6541) gives the triple
$$ \frac{1}{3}  + \frac{1}{11}  +\frac{1}{231}    $$
This leads to three quadruples using
$$ \frac{1}{a}  = \frac{1}{a+1}  +\frac{1}{a^2 + a} $$

These would be denominator quadruples
$$ (4,12,11,231) \mapsto (4,11,12,231), $$
$$ (3,12,132,231),  $$
$$ (3,11,232,53292).  $$
There are finitely many. We demand that denominators be written in increasing order. The first can be no larger then $4 \cdot( 7/3 ).$ If $10$ or larger,
$$ 4 (1/10) = 2 / 5 < 3/7 $$
For each choice of the first denominator, there is likewise a bound on the second denominator, and so on.